# Pulling a blank result

Tags: php, mysql

I have not found a solution to prevent this. I am using PHP to self populate my `option` fields so I don't have to manually add them all in. I have four `select` fields and three out of the four work perfect but the fourth one.

On the company field it will populate one blank field and then it populates the rest just fine. I have a solution for this that will remove this space but I was informed that it is not the best practice. Anyone think they know a better and more correct way of achieving this?

**PHP Select Field**

```
<label for="company">Company</label><br />
<select id="company" name="users" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
<?php include 'datalogin.php'; // Populates the Company select field

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT Company FROM `roster` ORDER BY Company ASC;");
  echo '<option value="">' . 'Select a Company' .'</option>';
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($row['Company'] == NULL) { //The empty if is to remove the blank space in the select field

        }
        else {
            echo '<option value="'.urlencode($row['Company']).'">'.htmlspecialchars($row['Company'],ENT_QUOTES).'</option>';
        }
  }
?>
</select>
```

Ideally I was told you should use "!" to tell the if statement to echo if it is not null but it still produces the blank space:

```
if ($row['Company'] !== NULL) {
    echo '<option value="'.urlencode($row['Company']).'">'.htmlspecialchars($row['Company'],ENT_QUOTES).'</option>';
}
```

This is what I mean by the blank space:

(Pretend it is a `select` field)

```
[Select a field]
[              ]
[Cleveland     ]
[Columbus      ]
[Toldeo        ]
```

[Live Agent Search Site](http://healthbenefitsohio.com/advance.php)

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT Company FROM roster WHERE Company IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Company ASC;");` the other issue may be the company is just blank and is not null

Comment: Remove one of your equal signs != Not !== but Christopher morrissey is right with the mysql

Comment: I am about to give your suggestion a try but the last time I checked my database I did see a couple people with a blank company field.

Comment: blank (not `NULL`) would be `WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(Company)) > 0`.  But if `NOT NULL` works, go with it.  PS - I always favor `GROUP BY` over `DISTINCT`, though for just one field it likely doesn't matter.

Comment: if it's blank, make sure it really *IS* blank, e.g. an empty string, and not an sql `null`.

Comment: It's a null and this worked perfectly guys! Thanks a million. The answer from Christopher is what I used but Wrikken also had a answer that worked great. Who should I give the answer to since Christopher used a comment?

Comment: @ebyrob I am very new to PHP and this is the first thing I have ever done in php. If you wouldn't mind explaining how `GROUP BY` works, I would greatly appreciate it! I can always look it up though so no biggy if your busy. :]

Comment: @JoshPowell I'm about to drive for an hour, but here's a quick link or two.  (or heck, post a question about it!)  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-modifiers.html  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Thanks a million buddy! I'll give those a quick read and if I need to, I'll post a question! Once again, thanks everyone that helped me out on this it was driving me nuts since I'm so anal with my sites lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Company 
FROM `roster` 
WHERE LENGTH(Company) > 0 
ORDER BY Company ASC;
```